# Java 8 peek vs map

Tags: java, java-8

I have following case: there is a list of objects - ProductData which contains several fields:

```
public class ProductData
{
....
  private String name;
  private String xref;

  //getters
  //setters
}
```

and there is API which returns list of following objects:

```
public class RatingTableRow
{
  private String planName;
  private String planXref;
  private int fromAge;
  private int toAge;
  private int ratingRegion;

 //constructor
 //getters
 //setters

}
```

but it returns objects with empty plan name field because it's not allowed during extraction of this object. I need to link product data with RatingTableRow by the xref in order to set plan name into the RatingTableRow because I need to use this object later so I created following code to do that:

```
Map<String, ProductData> productByXref = plans.stream()
        .collect(toMap(ProductData::getInternalCode, Function.identity()));

return getRatingTableRows(...).stream
        .filter(ratingRow -> productByXref.containsKey(ratingRow.getPlanXref()))
        .peek(row -> {
                ProductData product = productByXref.get(row.getPlanXref());
                row.setPlanName(product.getName());
        })....;
```

I know that java docs say that `peek` doesn't fit these needs but want to get your suggestions on how to make this task in more correct way.

Comment: How about `map` or `forEach` and `return row;` in the function?

Comment: If you want to modify the existing objects, I think `foreach` is the better choice.

Comment: can you please explain why foreach is better for that task?

Comment: Because `foreach` applies some code _for each_ element of the list, kind of like an old-style `for`-loop. But I just noticed those `...` after `peek`; is there more to the stream? `foreach` is a terminal stream operation, so in this case `peek` might indeed be the best way. BTW, what is that method supposed to `return`?

Comment: Uh, I don't think peek is bad here. map neither.

Comment: ... but then again, in this case you might want to split that stream. First set the plan names with `foreach`, and then stream again over the fixed list and do whatever comes next. Note that now, whatever comes after `peek` will also only be applied to the elements that pass the `filter`. Not sure if that's intentional.

Comment: Actually, I used that code as some API for another parts of the application and make it to return stream so new filtering/map chains can be added.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us: why did you choose to use `peek`, despite the warning in the documentation, instead of using the *terminal* operation `forEach` which is the correct way to apply an operation to each element of a stream. What are your needs, as this code doesn't tell us that.

Comment: So as I mentioned earlier I used it in some other places and decided to return stream. In some other place I added filtering call so currently it looks like a chain of executions.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There is a reason `peek` is documented to be *mainly for debugging purposes*.

Something that ends up being processed inside `peek` might not be eligible for the terminal operation at all and streams are executed only by a terminal operation.

Suppose a trivial example first:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .peek(x -> list.add(x))
            .map(x -> x * 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Everything looks fine right? Because `peek` will run for *all elements* in this case. But what happens when you add a `filter` (and forget about what `peek` did):

```
 .peek(x -> list.add(x))
 .map(x -> x * 2)
 .filter(x -> x > 8) // you have inserted a filter here
```

You are executing `peek` for every element, but *collecting none*. You sure you want that?

This can get even trickier:

```
    long howMany = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .peek(x -> list.add(x))
            .count();

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(howMany);
```

In java-8 the list is populated, *but in jdk-9* `peek` is not called at all. Since you are not using `filter` or `flatmap` you are not modifying the size of the Stream and `count` only needs it's size; **thus peek is not called at all**. Thus relying on `peek` is a very bad strategy.

Comment: Somebody needs to tell Jetbrains that, IntelliJ keeps telling me to replace my `map`s with `peek`s.

Comment: @CharlesWood really? (I don't use IntelliJ) if so, you should tell them about it... considering that so many smart people work there, this is probably even known or a config

Comment: Yeah once I actually read the popup it turns out it was because the function inside the `map` was returning the same object it was fed. IntelliJ just didn't realize that I was modifying it in the meantime.

Comment: @CharlesWood why should it care about modification? Isn't it just the same reference?

Comment: @AlexP11223, according to this answer right here, Java might decide to skip the `peek`s if it thinks you're not actually using them. `map` ensures that the operation takes place regardless. Not sure if that's what you're asking though.

Comment: @CharlesWood yeah, but you said that IntelliJ didn't detect that you modified the object in `map`. I think it has nothing to do with that, `peek` can get skipped regardless of the modification.

Comment: Could this be because the `map()`method is supposed to be free of side effects and you're returning the same object? That was at least the case for me.

Comment: `You are executing peek for every element, but collecting none. You sure you want that?`
I don't understand why that's a problem, the peek is before the filter, so it's expected to be executed for every element?

Comment: @xagaffar: Exactly. Software logic depends on execution order. I really don't see how it could be suprising to anyone.

Comment: On my side, I found the `peek()` method quite faster than the `map()` one (with return). Anyone have the same issue?

Comment: @CharlesWood - If I understand your scenario correctly, you are returning the same object reference inside the `map()` and possibly you are modifying the value of that object itself inside the `map()`. In this case, IntelliJ is correct in suggesting to use peek() - assuming you have a terminal operation in your stream - since you don't want to replace the element itself.

Comment: @SidharthRamesh Yep, after some more experience, I see the problem with modifying the contents of a list with a map! :)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201111