# .map vs .peek - Intellij suggestions

Tags: java

```
collection.stream().map(x -> {
    if(condition) {
        x.setY(true);
    }
    return x;
}).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I have a collection, and I want to set something in `x` variable when a certain condition is met. I'm doing it like it's shown in the code above. It does its job, and works. However, IntelliJ suggests that I swap `.map` with `.peek`. So the code would look like:

```
collection.stream().peek(x -> {
    if(condition) {
        x.setY(true);
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

It's one line shorter, but from what I read on peek documentation:

> API Note:
>   This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline:

So, is IntelliJ's suggestion misleading?

Comment: No, it's not misleading.

Comment: I think it's covered in [this StackOverflow question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370676/java-8-peek-vs-map).

Comment: @MCEmperor good catch.

Comment: Are you sure streaming is the best approach here in any case? Looks like standard iteration would be the way to go, since you're not doing anything to the stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example:

If you use `peek()` with `count()` in java 8, `peek()` will work, but if you use it in java 9, it won't unless you have `filter()`, because `count()` in java 9 doesn't go over all the elements.

You should prefer `forEach` to `peek`.

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
long c = l.stream().peek(System.out::println).count();
System.out.println(c);
```

Try the code above in java 8 and 9 and see the difference. My point is that you should follow what the API documentation says and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

No is not misleading.
The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) states:

> peek
>
> Stream peek(Consumer action)
>
> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally
> **performing the provided action** on each element as elements are **consumed** from the
> resulting stream.

The JavaDoc is very clear that peek have the ability to modify the stream.

Comment: _"The JavaDoc is very clear that peek have the ability to modify the stream"_ → ... as long as it gets actually executed, that is. From Java 9 onwards, stream optimization might drop `peek` entirely if it doen't affect the end result (eg. `stream().peek(...).count()` doesn't need to execute `peek` in order to get the result). So yes: IntelliJ is misleading you when it says `.map()` can always be replaced by `.peek()`.