# Can I combine these two into one?

Tags: java, lambda

Been looking around and trying to teach myself streaming api. I made a couple classes that list an arraylist of pets and theres an abstract method to display the pets sound it works fine with these two expressions seperate

```
pets.stream().parallel().forEach(System.out::println);
pets.stream().parallel().forEach(s -> s.sound());
```

but I want to see if I could combine them into one line of code so after the list prints it prints the sound. Is there any reference code for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: `map(s -> sounds()).forEach(System.out::println)`?

Comment: or `.peek(Pet::sound).forEach(System.out::println)`.

Comment: @Eugene This works iff. `sound()` returns the instance itself

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks that did just what I wanted it to do.

Comment: @SkyePomerantz I recommend taking a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66934400/4216641). If possible, I would suggest not using `.peek(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
pets.stream().parallel().forEach(s -> { System.out.println(s); s.sound(); });
```

Remember, lambda is really just an implementation of an interface and you can put any code in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to wrap both operations (calling `sound()` and printing the pet) in a static helper-method, even if this may reorder the print-statements (but the order is nondeterministic anyway due to concurrency):

```
private static void printSoundAndPet(Pet pet) {
  final Optional<Pet> maybePet = Optional.ofNullable(pet);
  maybePet.ifPresent(Pet::sound);
  maybePet.map(Pet::toString)
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

This would then allow the following stream-operation:

```
pets.stream().parallel()
    .forEach(Ideone::printSoundAndPet);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/StaLOA)

---

The program may show unexpected behaviour. For this, please take a look at [user15358848](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15358848/user15358848)'s comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934152/can-i-combine-these-two-into-one#comment118315693_66934196) and [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059372/eugene)'s comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934152/can-i-combine-these-two-into-one#comment118315696_66934196). I suggest dropping the `.parallel()`-operation. This would then simplify

```
pets.stream().parallel().forEach(....);
```

to just

```
pets.forEach(...);
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
pets.stream().parallel()
. peek(System.out::println)
 .forEach(s -> s.sound());
```

Comment: in theory because of the specification of `forEach`, you could see no output at all. just like [in this example at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370676/java-8-peek-vs-map/44371170#44371170)